# how to get the list of medias attached to a page?

Tags: wordpress

I created a template (call it A.php) for a specific set of pages on my website.
How would one retrieve the list of medias (previously) attached to a page whose template is A.php in A.php?
I want to be able to iterate through that list of media in this A.php template. Here is a minimalistic version of A.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: test layout 
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage jbWeb 
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header();


query_posts(array('pagename' => get_query_var('pagename')));

while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        ob_start();
        the_title();
        $title = ob_get_clean();
        echo $title;
        $medias = get_attached_media( 'image', get_the_ID());
        foreach($medias as $media) {
                echo ('this is a url: ' . wp_get_attachment_url($media->id));
        }

}

get_footer();
?>
```

apparently the only post that is retrieved from the `while(have_posts())` loop is the page itself (or is it the content of the page itself?). This is what is shown on my browser:
[image]
The Url of any media attached to the page is never shown. And there are only two medias when I attached four photos to "pagetest1".
Here is what my admin page for the page "pagetest1" looks like:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the url of a existing media in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901499/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-existing-media-in-wordpress)

Comment: So to clarify, you need to get a list of media attached to any page that is using the `A.php` template? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NathanDawson Yes exactly. I edited my post to add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a solution I have found which allows for any type of media to be displayed (you just have to tweak a part of the solution I will show how):

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 * Template Name: test layout 
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage jbWeb 
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header();


//the query to select the post id of the post containing all content of this page.
//have to replace pageTest by get_query_var('pagename')
$page_content = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("
                select post_content from (select max(post_date) as post_date from wp_posts
                        where post_title='%s' group by post_title) as sub, 
                        wp_posts as p where p.post_date = sub.post_date ;",
                get_query_var('pagename'))
);

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/<img.*\/>/mU', $page_content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
        foreach ($m as $m1) {
                echo $m1 . "\n";
        }
}

get_footer();
?>
```

**Explanation:**

**The mysql query**
So first there is that query on the mysql database that is done where I select the content of the most recent version of the post intrinsic to the page whose template is "test layout". I pass get_query_var('pagename') as parameter to this mysql query, this get_query_var function returns the current page name.

**the pattern match**
Then I find all occurences of the `<img/>` tag within the content of that post. About the m and U option within the pattern: m signifies that I want the input $page_content to be seen as a single line. And U signifies that I want the regexp to not be greedy, so that I find all tags and not simply one tag that would contain other tags.

**printing the result**
Finally the double foreach loop prints all `<img/>` tag within that resulting page.

**Note**: You could find all occurences of a `<video/>` tag in the same way. Just replace `<img.*\/>` within the pattern by `<video.*\/>`